# Как в проверке указать любое значение?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток
Мне нужно в этой проверке

```
if (window.location.href != "http://example.ru/") {alert(1)} else {alert(0)}
```

указать что после http://example.ru/ может быть любое значение, проверять только поддомен ( типа http://krasnoyarsk.example.ru/), не знаю как реализовать по неопытности

Comment: скорее всего тут подойдет [`location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/origin) хотя похоже он мало где поддерживается :-) или [`location.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/host)

Comment: Подошло) И нашел что с поддержкой можно справиться) Спасибо

Comment: можешь добавить свой ответ